# PHP: Linking two tables to show data correctly using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables connected in a different way than I want them, and I will try my best to explain what I am searching for, together with what I have accomplished myself so far.

What I am searching for:
First of all, I have a table `objects_price` and a table `materials`. These tables are shown beneath:

`objects_price`:

[image: table objects_price]

`materials`:

[image: table materials]

Okay so I have some objects which can be a chair, table or whatever furniture you can imaging. All objects are connected to a third table with information about the object. Each object requires some sort of material in order to be crafted. As you can see in the `objects_price` table, the object with an `id` of 1 requires 47 of the material equal to 1. Which is `Oak Log` as you can see in the `materials` table.

The object with an id of 2 requires two materials, material 2 and 3. and it requires 20 of `Stone` and 30 of `Birch log`

To make everything a little more clear, heres an image displaying what I just explained:

[image: displaying what I just said above]

What I have so far is two queries where one of them doesn't do what I want it to, especially because I am using an array to display the materials and the amount but what my code does is that it displays all of the materials in all of the objects, it looks like this right now:

[image: what it is like now]

The problem lies in this query and the way it creates an array:

```
$query = 'SELECT objects_price.object_id, materials.material_id, materials.name, material_amount
FROM objects_price
LEFT JOIN materials USING(material_id)';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$arr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[$row['name']][] = $row['material_amount'];
}
```

together with the way I provide the objects with their corresponding materials:

```
foreach($arr as $name => $objects) {
?>
<p><?php echo $name; ?><i style="float:right;"><?php foreach($objects as $material_amount) { echo $material_amount; } ?></i></p>
<?php
}
```

I hope I made it clear and please tell me if you want me to provide more code, more images or explanation or anything like that. Any help, advice or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, for one, you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your query to limit to a specific `object_id`. Second, you probably want to use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: uhm yeah, but I want to insert all materials and their amount in the array, and make them display it one at a time corresponding to the object with the same id as the `object_id` in `objects_price` thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[$row['object_id']][$row['name']] = $row['material_amount'];
    }
```

....

foreach ($arr as $key){

```
$material_array = $key;

foreach ($material_array as $k => $v){
echo "<p>$k | $v</p>";
}
```

It will display material name and amount correctly, but there are no names of objects themselves.

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried your code and it resulted in all objects requring the same materials. So theres no different of the objects.

Comment: I would prent out the results of the query to see what's actually being returned. If all seems fine, I would print_r($arr).  I had created an array manually, as I don't want to re-create your tables like this: 
$arr = array();
$arr[1]['birch_log'] = 20;
$arr[1]['stone'] = 30;

$arr[2]['birch_log'] = 40;
$arr[2]['stone'] = 60;
$arr[2]['oak_log'] = 100;

Comment: It would seem then that you are not getting correct results from the query.

Comment: Hmm not quite sure what results I am looking for then, I guess. Do we want to put everything inside the array?

Comment: You need to do a print_r of $arr to see if that seems correct. I'ts a good idea o just run a query in Mysql without php to see what you get in a result set.

Comment: I get this: `Array ( [1] => Array ( [Oak log] => 47 ) [2] => Array ( [Stone] => 20 [Birch log] => 30 ) [3] => Array ( [Stone] => 40 ) )` This seems correct though. It must be something with the query then? It doesn't know what material belongs to what object

Comment: That actually seems correct completely per your table in thec context of what you have provided, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50996/discussion-between-owwyess-and-ar)